Unable To Create Bottle | Bottles Linux
Details
Was creating a bottle when it said Unable to create bottle
Log
Generating bottle configuration…
The Wine config is being updated…
Wine config updated!
Running as Flatpak, sandboxing userdir…
Setting Windows version…
Apply CMD default settings…
Optimizing environment…
Applying environment: gaming…
Installing DXVK…
Installing VKD3D…
Installing dependency: Microsoft d3dx9 DLLs from DirectX 9 redistributable …
Installing dependency: Microsoft Line Services …
Installing dependency: Microsoft Arial Font …
Installing dependency: Microsoft Times New Roman Font …
Installing dependency: Microsoft Courier New Font …
Installing dependency: Microsoft d3dcompiler_43.dll …
Failed to install dependency: Microsoft d3dcompiler_43.dll

I was trying to create a Bottle to run some Windows 10 games. I have Wine64 installed (couldn't install wine32 because it said You have held packages).
I have tried nothing so far because I couldn't find a solution for this online (not even GitHub).

Maybe you should try this:
https://github.com/bottlesdevs/Bottles/issues/2491
And you also can try build Bottles from source because ubuntu have old packages in repo's
